# How to configure Dokka to generate documentation only for specific classes?

Tags: kotlin-dokka

I am working on an SDK, and I noticed that when using Dokka, it generates documentation for all interfaces. However, I only want to generate documentation for the interfaces that are exposed to developers. How can I configure this in my build.gradle file? Currently, I haven't made any configurations and I'm using the default settings.

I went through the documentation, but I still couldn't find how to configure Dokka.